# Notation: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Show that the elements 2,3, and $1 \pm \sqrt{-5}$ are irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.  I have never seen this notation before.  From another post I am interpreting this to mean the following:

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] = \{a_{0}+a_{1}\sqrt{-5}+ \dots + a_{n}(\sqrt{-5})^{n} \colon a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}     \}$.

Am I correct or is it something else?  I do not need the proof, just verification of notation.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{-5}^2 = -5$, so you don't need all those terms. Also, the power should not be under the root - that will cause confusion on the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, but it it suffices to see that $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}] = \{a_0 + a_1\sqrt{-5}: a_i \in \mathbb Z \}$

Comment: Why are the other powers of $\sqrt{-5}$ not needed?

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt{-5})^{2k} \in \mathbb Z$ and $(\sqrt{-5})^{2k+1} \in \sqrt{-5} \mathbb Z$  for every $k$

Answer (score 0):

It's somehow correct, but it is misleading.
The correct way to understand this notation is 
$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]=\{a+b\mathrm i\sqrt5\,\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: There's no reason to write $\sqrt{-5}$ as $i\sqrt{5}$...

Comment: @paulgarrett. The OP meant $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ such that $\alpha^2=-5$. The notation $\sqrt{-5}$ is obsolete and misleading since $\sqrt{-5}\sqrt{-5}\neq\sqrt{(-5)(-5)}$.

Comment: No, it is certainly not obsolete at all. (The possibility of mis-using products of square roots is irrelevant, and bringing $\sqrt{-1}$ into the picture doesn't help anything.)

Comment: "bringing $\sqrt{-1}$ into the picture doesn't help anything". I can only agree with that, since this notation makes no more sense than $\log(-1)/37\pi$ or $0/0$.

Comment: I guess you and I are in different worlds of mathematical usage. I agree that square roots of negative numbers oughtn't be introduced to early... but in introductory abstract algebra or introductory algebraic number theory, writing $\sqrt{-5}$ or $\sqrt{-1}$ is certainly conventional usage. Not for grade-schoolers, no. Also, $\log(-1)$ is $\pi i$ ambiguous by multiples of $2\pi i$. Care is required, but it has sense. I think at the level of the question, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is apt, and is at least completely standard.